# Attribute is not being displayed on page product

Tags: product, product-attribute, custom, view

I want to display a custom attribute on my product view page. It's a dropdown menu with 2 options 'LRG' and 'SML'.

The idea is that user can select one of these options. This is the link:

http://store.hbros.co.uk/chicken-wrap.html

I've already selected the 'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end' to 'Yes' but it's not being displayed.

What could I do?

Answer (score 2):

If this attribute is related to the product, you’ll better use some custom options in Magento. They will not only properly be displayed on the frontend (checkbox select, radio-button, file, etc.), but also will be correctly transmitted throughout the chain of the product-order life cycle in the system.

You will see the correct value in the shopping cart, quote, order and invoice. If you don’t have enough custom options, you can always search the Magento marketplace for the extensions like Advanced Product Options, which will extend the standard platform functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Its cache issue. Please try to clear your cache and do indexing, attribute will display at product view page.